# Using Piecewise in RevolutionPlot3D

Tags: plotting

The [documentation for `RevolutionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html) shows that you can specify a parametric curve like this:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{u, u}, {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd like to do this with a `Piecewise` function for `{fx,fz}`:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Piecewise[{{{u, u}, u < 0.5}, {{u, 0.5}, u >= 0.5}}], {u, 0,
   1}]
```

but I get messages and a blank plot:

> Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

whereas a `Piecewise` function for `{fx,fz}` works in `ParametricPlot`, for example:

```
ParametricPlot[Piecewise[{{{u, u}, u < 0.5}, {{u, 0.5}, u >= 0.5}}], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By writing `Piecewise` expressions for `fx` and `fz` separately, it works:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{Piecewise[{{u, u < 0.5}, {u, u >= 0.5}}], 
    Piecewise[{{u, u < 0.5}, {0.5, u >= 0.5}}]}, {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How is it possible to piece together a function for `{fx,fz}` in `RevolutionPlot3D`?

Comment: Interesting... `RevolutionPlot3D[Function[t, {t, t}][u], {u, 0, 1}]` doesn't work either.

Comment: You could try `RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[cone[u]], {u, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: Thanks @Heike. Indeed, it turns out my toy example was too simple for the problem I have, which involves a `Piecewise` function. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: @J.M. I've updated the question example using Piecewise, which was my actual problem. It's probably related to the example in your comment.

Comment: Hmm, `RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[Boole[u < 0.5] {u, u} + Boole[u >= 0.5] {u, 0.5}], {u, 0, 1}]` works well (using Heike's suggestion); if you remove the `Evaluate[]`, it fails. Very peculiar...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the first note under More Information of the documentation, the form `RevolutionPlot3D[fz,{t,...}]` is short form for `RevolutionPlot3D[{t,0,fz},{t,...}]`.

To invoke the form you want, you need to call `RevolutionPlot3D` with a list of two elements, avoiding triggering the short form above:

```
pw[u_] := Piecewise[{{{u, u}, u < 0.5}, {{u, 0.5}, u >= 0.5}}]

RevolutionPlot3D[{pw[u][[1]], pw[u][[2]]}, {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

This misses that there is a discontinuity at 0.5, so it does not exclude it from the plot. You can get the original plot by adding `Exclusions -> {u == 0.5}`:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{pw[u][[1]], pw[u][[2]]}, {u, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {u == 0.5}]
```

[image]

Update per comment from J. M.:

```
Evaluate[Boole[u < 0.5] {u, u} + Boole[u >= 0.5] {u, 0.5}]
```

works as well, because it evaluates to:

```
{u Boole[u >= 0.5] + u Boole[u < 0.5], 0.5 Boole[u >= 0.5] + u Boole[u < 0.5]}
```

This does detect the discontinuity, but of course has the drawback that the input had to be rewritten from a Piecewise:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Evaluate[Boole[u < 0.5] {u, u} + Boole[u >= 0.5] {u, 0.5}], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: That precludes constructions like `RevolutionPlot3D[BSplineFunction[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}][u], {u, 0, 1}]`, I guess.

Comment: Your input won't work directly, but there is nothing stopping you from defining a `bspl[u_]:=BSplineFunction[...]` and then calling the plot similar as with `pw` in my answer.

Comment: Interestingly, my plot also has problems with the discontinuity.

Comment: Turns out it purposefully excludes it. If you want it filled, you can add `Exclusions -> None` to the plot call. My version is a black box to the plot function, so it does not detect the discontinuity. (Edited answer to reflect this.)